# How to use apply and map function on tf dataset with custom function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-transform

I am trying to understand how to use map and apply function in TensorFlow. Objective is to use all the basic data pre-processing step while reading the data into TensorFlow as map gives an option to parallelize the operation.

```
a_list = [b"THis is for Testing"]
```

## converting a_list into tf dataset format

```
a_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(a_list)

print(list(a_dataset.as_numpy_iterator()))
[array([b'THis is for Testing'], dtype=object)]
```

## Applying map to calculate len of list

```
a_dataset_len = a_dataset.map(lambda x: len(x))

print(list(a_dataset_len.as_numpy_iterator()))

[1]
```

## Applying map to convert all strings into lowercase

```
a_dataset_lower = a_dataset.map(lambda x: x.lower())
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

## Using apply function on a_list

```
a_dataset.apply(lambda x:len(x))
TypeError: object of type 'TensorDataset' has no len()
```

Please help me to understand

1. Why I am failing to use apply function using len(x) while map is
   able to execute ?
2. How to create own custom function and use the pre-built one to pass it during Dataset.map and Dataset.apply?

Comment: Elements in a dataset are TensorFlow tensors, not Python lists or strings. You cannot use `len`, you should use [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape), or if what you want is the length of the strings, [`tf.strings.length`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/length). You also cannot use `lower`, you should use [`tf.strings.lower`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/lower).

Comment: Also, consider whether you need [`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensors) or [`tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices).

Comment: Thank you jdehsea . So this mean everything must be according to Tensors not numpy ? Then how to create our own function ? any idea or link with example ?

Comment: You can use your own functions, but you should use TensorFlow functions to operate the values, and return TensorFlow tensors.